# dplyr mutate: Using variables defined in mutate in definition of other variables in same mutate

Tags: r, scope, dplyr

I am trying to take about 8 million records, divide them into equal groups by quantile (deciles in my real application), and then find the mean of each group. This is I hope a reproducible example:

```
require(Hmisc)  # for weighted functions

year    <- c(10,10,20,20,30,30)
hhinc99 <- c(101,102,301,301,501,502)
wtsupp  <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.11)

midy    <- tibble(year, hhinc99, wtsupp)

 midy  %>% 
   group_by(year)   %>% 
   mutate(inc2 <- hhinc99, 
          inc_q_groups <- cut(inc2, breaks = 
                                wtd.quantile(hhinc99, 
                                             weights = wtsupp, 
                                             probs=c(0, .5, 0)))  %>% 
            group_by(inc_q_groups)   %>% 
            summarize(inc_q_means <- 
                        wtd.mean(hhinc99, weights = wtsupp, na.rm=TRUE))) -> 
   inc_dec_means
```

When I run this code I get the following error.

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'inc2' not found.
```

I've written functions before where a mutate variable is defined in terms of another mutate variable defined to its left. Not sure why not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to do with you using `<-` for assignment inside the mutate rather than `=`.

```r
library(tidyverse)                      
require(Hmisc)  # for weighted functions

year    <- c(10,10,20,20,30,30)         
hhinc99 <- c(101,102,301,301,501,502)   
wtsupp  <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.11)  

midy    <- tibble(year, hhinc99, wtsupp)

midy  %>%                               
group_by(year)   %>%                    
mutate(inc2 <- hhinc99)  

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   year [3]
#>    year hhinc99 wtsupp `inc2 <- hhinc99`
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1    10     101   1.10               101
#> 2    10     102   1.20               102
#> 3    20     301   1.30               301
#> 4    20     301   1.50               301
#> 5    30     501   1.70               501
#> 6    30     502   1.11               502
```

Comment: After implementing your fix, I got a ""breaks are not unique" error, so I added some jitter to hhinc99. That got rid of the not unique error, and no I get this one:Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: unused arguments (weights = wtsupp, probs = c(0:10/10)).

Comment: (ooops. hit retrurn) Not sure how mutate can even see weights and probs? These are arguments to wtd.quantile, which itself is an argument to cut.I've upvoted you & will accept your answer regardless, but if you have thoughts on this new error revealed by fixing the old one (and subsequent) they would be most welcome.